# how to set tablecell row height automatically based on inner view outlet?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I want to set tableview cell height automatically to show the label completely without happening like that?

[image]

Any help?

Comment: How do you calculate label height ? Is it fixed or dynamic ?

Comment: http://puu.sh/lwTR7/7d52d389b5.png   and H=26,W=456

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411099/tell-uitablecell-the-height-of-uitextview-dynamically

Comment: @AlexVogel,I really need pure swift help,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things that you need to do:

1st thing: Set AutoLayout for it.
2nd thing: implement these code:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

You can see more from my project: https://github.com/khuong291/Yelp

Comment: http://puu.sh/lwU7p/3d686104e2.png. It worked.but,my image icon appear like that,any ideas?

Comment: That's depend on what you set with AutoLayout.

Comment: It looks like you may have added a `bottom to superview` constraint for your image, which got stretched when the cell grew.

Comment: @Losiowaty,I still can't solve the image keep stretching.;(=> http://puu.sh/lwUHr/82549d67b0.png

Comment: double click the constraint

Comment: Each component view must have relationship with the others.